# Best way to mark a pybind11-binding as deprecated

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ class with Python bindings using pybind11.

Now I want to mark the binding of one method as deprecated.  Let's assume it looks something like this:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<Foobar>(m, "PyFoobar")
        .def("old_foo", &Foobar::foo)  // <-- this is deprecated in favour of "new_foo"
        .def("new_foo", &Foobar::foo);
}
```

What is the best way to mark `PyFoobar.old_foo()` as deprecated such that the user notices it when calling the method?  Ideally I would like a `DeprecationWarning` to be triggered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, here is my working example. I actually couldn't figure out to call the imported python function with a Python C Type, so I just went straight to the C API, which should perform better anyway

```
struct Foobar {
  Foobar() {}

  void foo(int32_t art) {}

};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {

  pybind11::class_<Foobar>(m, "PyFoobar")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("old_foo",
          [](pybind11::object &self, int arg_to_foo)
          {
            PyErr_WarnEx(PyExc_DeprecationWarning, 
                         "old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.", 
                         1);
              return self.attr("new_foo")(arg_to_foo);
          })
    .def("new_foo", &Foobar::foo);
}
```

You can pass any of the warning types from here as the first argument:
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#standard-warning-categories

The final int is the level of the stack that you want to be flagged as being deprecated.

So looking at this python code

```
import example

import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("default")

def mary():
    f = example.PyFoobar()
    f.old_foo(1)

mary()
```

If you set the stack level to `1` you'll get

```
test.py:9: DeprecationWarning: old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.
  f.old_foo(1)
```

You might want `2` which will give you the actual calling context, but depends on what your use case is

```
test.py:11: DeprecationWarning: old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.
  mary()
```

It is also important to note that by default, many versions of python have Deprecation warnings turned off. You can check this by checking the value of
`warnings.filters`. That is why in my example I have the call to `warnings.simplefilter("default")` which enables all types of warnings, but only the first time they are hit. There are other ways you can control this as well, including using the `-W` flag when running python or an environment variable.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: I'm leaving this here for reference but other answers have better solutions, so better use them.*

---

I found some way to get most of what I want: Use a lambda for the deprecated binding.  In this lambda, issue the warning and then call the actual function.  As in my example, the only change is the name, I simply call `new_foo` inside `old_foo`.  If the actual function that is bound differs, this would get more complicated.

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<Foobar>(m, "PyFoobar")
        .def("old_foo",
             [](pybind11::object &self, int arg_to_foo)
             {
                 auto warnings = pybind11::module::import("warnings");
                 warnings.attr("warn")(
                     "old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.");

                 return self.attr("new_foo")(arg_to_foo);
             })
        .def("new_foo", &Foobar::foo);
}
```

This results in

> UserWarning: old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.

When `old_foo()` is called for the first time.

Unfortunately, I did not yet figure out how to make it a `DeprecationWarning` instead of `UserWarning`.

Comment: Try passing PyExc_DeprecationWarning as the second argument to "warn"

Comment: @JesseC It seems that I need to convert `PyExe_DeprecationWarning` to the correct type. Do you know how to do this? When I just do `warnings.attr("warn")("...", PyExe_DeprecationWarning);`, I get the following error at runtime: `RuntimeError: make_tuple(): unable to convert argument of type '_object*' to Python object`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @luator answer and the question how to emit `DeprecationWarning` instead of `UserWarning`, this worked for me (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to reply with a comment):

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<Foobar>(m, "PyFoobar")
        .def("old_foo",
             [](pybind11::object &self, int arg_to_foo)
             {
                 auto warnings = pybind11::module::import("warnings");
                 auto builtins = pybind11::module::import("builtins");
                 warnings.attr("warn")(
                     "old_foo() is deprecated, use new_foo() instead.",
                      builtins.attr("DeprecationWarning"));

                 return self.attr("new_foo")(arg_to_foo);
             })
        .def("new_foo", &Foobar::foo);
}
```